# Changing the super administrator password WSO2 IOTS 3.1.0

Tags: wso2-iot

I dowloaded **WSO2 IoT Server 3.1.0-M8 version**. I want to change **super admin password** and I followed the instructions in documentation

> Changing
>   the Super Administrator Password and in tab 'Changing Password via
>   file configuration'. I have changed admin password to new one in all
>   configuration files mentioned in documentation. I've also changed
>   [wso2iothome]/conf/api-manager.xml by replacing ${admin.password}
>   entries with my new password. I connect to ApacheDS LDAP server and
>   get super admin user successfully. I have changed passwords in the
>   Property name="ConnectionPassword"> entry in user-mgt.xml file.    I
>   started server by running start-all.sh in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine. It
>   gives following error:
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-07-25 09:20:27,259]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.registry.eventing.internal.RegistryEventingServiceComponent}
>   -  Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry {org.wso2.carbon.registry.eventing.internal.RegistryEventingServiceComponent}
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2017-07-25 09:20:27,349]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} -  JMX Service URL  :
>   service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} TID: [-1234] []
>   [2017-07-25 09:20:27,350]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.url.printer.URLPrinterStartupHandler} - 
>   IoT Console URL : https://localhost:9443/devicemgt
>   {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.url.printer.URLPrinterStartupHandler} TID:
>   [-1234] [] [2017-07-25 09:20:27,369]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - 
>   Server           :  WSO2 IoT Server-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} TID:
>   [-1234] [] [2017-07-25 09:20:27,370]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - 
>   WSO2 Carbon started in 97 sec
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} TID:
>   [-1234] [] [2017-07-25 09:20:27,648]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console
>   URL  : https:// localhost:9443/carbon/
>   {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} TID: [-1234] []
>   [2017-07-25 09:20:31,938] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor}
>   -  Authentication failed. Please check your username/password {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor}
>   TID: [-1] [] [2017-07-25 09:20:32,071] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler} -
>   failed to publish api.
>   {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler}
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.exception.APIManagerPublisherException:
>   feign.FeignException: status 401 reading
>   DCRClient#register(ClientProfile)     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherServiceImpl.publishAPI(APIPublisherServiceImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler.publishAPIs(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:97)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler.access$500(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:30)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler$1.run(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:69)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   feign.FeignException: status 401 reading
>   DCRClient#register(ClientProfile)     at
>   feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62)  at
>   feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91)     at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
>     at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.register(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.OAuthRequestInterceptor.apply(OAuthRequestInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.targetRequest(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:88)
>     at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.apisGet(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherServiceImpl.publishAPI(APIPublisherServiceImpl.java:53)
>     ... 4 more

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 IoT Server 3.1.0 is now released. Can you try the steps in the released version, please? It should work for it.

[1] http://wso2.com/iot

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Changing+the+Password